# MySQL WHERE NOT EXISTS not working

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have two tables, one called st_grid that has soccer matches in it, and another table, st_compiled, that is essentially a copy of st_grid but the process of putting a row in st_compiled is quite intensive so I want to put the data in one row at a time. The two tables are like this with the pertinent columns:

1. st_grid

   - id
   - league_id
   - fixture_date
2. inplay_fixture_compiled

   - inplay_fixture_compiled_id
   - grid_id

I want to select a row from st_grid where there is no corresponding row in st_compiled ON grid_id, but I havent had any luck. I have looked up various queries and am trying this one

```
                    SELECT g.id
                    FROM st_grid g
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS
                                (SELECT i.grid_id
                                FROM inplay_fixture_compiled i
                                WHERE g.id = i.grid_id)
                    AND g.league_id = '15'
```

But it isnt working, all that is happening is the page is hanging for minutes when I try and run it. There is about 170,000 rows in st_grid (but for each league_id there will max 600 rows) and 10,000 in st_compiled but I dont believe that that is a huge amount by any means.

Hope that makes sense, any help much appreciated.
P

Comment: You are saying st_compiled but used inplay_fixture_compiled table in sub query. Which one is correct ?

Comment: Pls include the results of the explain and list all indexes you have in the two tables.

Comment: WHERE g.id  should this be WHERE g.grid_id?

Comment: Although the other answers provide correct solutions, your query seems correct to me. Are you sure your problem isn't somewhere else? Also, the `g.id` shouldn't be `g.grid_id` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try join in the case to get all the data in st_grid that is not yet exists in st_compiled.

For e.g;

```
select grid_id 
from st_grid t1 
left join st_compiled t2 on t1.grid_id = st_compiled.grid_id 
where t2.grid_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT g.grid_id
 FROM st_grid g
 LEFT JOIN inplay_fixture_compiled i ON (g.id = i.grid_id) 
 WHERE g.league_id = '15' and i.grid_id is null.
```

You can join these tables with a LEFT JOIN keyword and filter out the NULL's, but this will likely be less efficient than using NOT EXISTS.